# react state not updating inside callabck

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm not understanding why the following code, the callback onSocketMessage is not using the new acquisition state. inside the useEffect the state is correctly updated, but the function is not evaluated again...i've also tryed using useCallback with acquisition as dependency but nothing changed.

```
const Ac = () => {
  const [acquisition, setAcquisition] = useState({ data: {} })
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const socket = useRef(null);


  const onSocketMessage = (message) => {
    console.log(acquisition) // this is always initial state
    let { data } = acquisition
    data.input[message.index] = message.input
 
    setAcquisition(prevState => ({ ...prevState, data }));
  }

   


  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCurrentAcquisition(acquisition => {
      setAcquisition(acquisition)
      setLoading(false)
      socket.current = newSocket('/acquisition', () => console.log('connected'), onSocketMessage);
    })


    return () => socket.current.disconnect()
  }, [])


  console.log(acquisition)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are logging a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) you should try the following instead:

```
const onSocketMessage = useCallback((message) => {
  setAcquisition((acquisition) => {
    //use acquisition in the callback
    console.log(acquisition);
    //you were mutating state here before
    return {
      ...acquisition,
      data: {
        ...acquisition.data,
        input: {
          //not sure if this is an array or not
          //assimung it is an object
          ...acquisition.data.input,
          [message.index]: message.input,
        },
      },
    };
  });
}, []); //only created on mount

useEffect(() => {
  fetchCurrentAcquisition((acquisition) => {
    setAcquisition(acquisition);
    setLoading(false);
    socket.current = newSocket(
      '/acquisition',
      () => console.log('connected'),
      onSocketMessage
    );
  });

  return () => socket.current.disconnect();
  //onSocketMessage is a dependency of the effect
}, [onSocketMessage]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast replay, now i think i got it, but this Will only work linke this right? The component render is updating the function varibles but the closure Will always use the initial state, in general if i have to use a state inside a function i have to pass it as a param or use the prev state in the set function correct?

Comment: @claud.io Yes, you should use the prev state in the set function for this handler because the effect only runs on mount and passes the handler to the socket at that time. The handler will have acquisition available as a closure but the value of it is the value it was when the component mounted because that's the only time you pass the handler to the socket.

Comment: thanks, but how can i handle a closure with like this if i need to read multiple states?